# How to assign weights to a set of ordered objects?

Tags: weights, weighted-regression, weighted-data

I have been trying to assign weights to set of objects. The problem that I have is as following.

I have a set of objects ordered either ascending or decending.
. Each object shall be provided a weight that is in between 0 and 1, either ascending or decending corresponding to the order of the objects.
. The weights cannot be repeated
. Sum of the weights shall be 1

I would appreicate infos with regards to algorithms  and methods that I can look into.

Comment: Why not generate numbers uniform on (0,1), normalise them to add to 1 and then sort them? I suspect I have completely  missed the point of what you are doing which is why this is only a comment not an answer.

Comment: Literally *any* set of distinct positive numbers will work: divide each by their sum to make the resulting weights sum to unity; sort them; and assign them, in order, to your sorted objects.  Since this clearly has nothing to do with any property of the objects (other than their count), its utility or applicability to any form of data analysis is obscure.  Would you mind telling what you hope this will achieve?

Comment: @Whuber, perfect! This gives exactly what I want. I would assign objects a number from 1 to N and divide by the sum of the values give me what I would be looking for. This is to assign the weights in a set of objects. Each set can have same objects but their weights differ by the time they have arrived into the set. In the end I would like to sum  the weights of the objects over many sets to decide the ranking of the objects. Does it make any sense?

Comment: @mdewey, i am not sure if understand you correctly.

Comment: It works mathematically.  I haven't been able to understand your intended application.

Comment: Intended application is, I have m vectors where a finite number of objects are appended to each vector. The objects arrive to vectors based on a hidden process. I would like to assign a highest weight to the object that appended first and lowest weight that appended the last in a vector. I
Once all the m vectors are filled, I would like to sort the objects based on the weighted sum. Does it make any sense?

Comment: Mathematically it works, but it is difficult to see what it actually accomplishes, since the result depends arbitrarily on how you determine the weights--and, as we have seen, there are a great many ways to do that.